# If-elif-else combined with group-by to create new column

Tags: python, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have the first 4 columns, and I want to create the *5th one:

```
user     date             visit_num     total_visits_user          *last_cust__visit*
1       1995-10-01            1                2                     1995-10-02 
1       1995-10-02            2                2                     1995-10-02  
2       1995-10-01            1                3                     1995-10-03
2       1995-10-02            2                3                     1995-10-03
2       1995-10-03            3                3                     1995-10-03
3       1995-10-01            1                5                     1995-10-05
3       1995-10-02            2                5                     1995-10-05
3       1995-10-03            3                5                     1995-10-05
3       1995-10-04            4                5                     1995-10-05
3       1995-10-05            5                5                     1995-10-05
4       1995-10-03            1                2                     1995-10-04
4       1995-10-04            2                2                     1995-10-04
```

***last_cust_ visit** is a new column showing the date of the last visit of a customer.

I tried if, elif, else combined with groupby, but unforunately I could not make it work.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try and explain your problem more. And provide your code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could groupby on `user` to get the max of `date` and merge this with the original dataframe:

```
df['last_cust_visit'] = df.merge(df.groupby('user')['date'].max()
                                 .reset_index(), on='user', suffixes=('_', '')
                                 )['date']
```

It gives the expected:

```
    user        date  visit_num  total_visits_user last_cust_visit
0      1  1995-10-01          1                  2      1995-10-02
1      1  1995-10-02          2                  2      1995-10-02
2      2  1995-10-01          1                  3      1995-10-03
3      2  1995-10-02          2                  3      1995-10-03
4      2  1995-10-03          3                  3      1995-10-03
5      3  1995-10-01          1                  5      1995-10-05
6      3  1995-10-02          2                  5      1995-10-05
7      3  1995-10-03          3                  5      1995-10-05
8      3  1995-10-04          4                  5      1995-10-05
9      3  1995-10-05          5                  5      1995-10-05
10     4  1995-10-03          1                  2      1995-10-04
11     4  1995-10-04          2                  2      1995-10-04
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use `transform` method of `pd.groupby`:

```
df["last_cust_visit"] = df.groupby("user")["date"].transform('max')
```

With `transform` output dataframe will have same number of rows as `df`:

```
    user        date  visit_num  total_visits_user last_cust_visit
0      1  1995-10-01          1                  2      1995-10-02
1      1  1995-10-02          2                  2      1995-10-02
2      2  1995-10-01          1                  3      1995-10-03
3      2  1995-10-02          2                  3      1995-10-03
4      2  1995-10-03          3                  3      1995-10-03
5      3  1995-10-01          1                  5      1995-10-05
6      3  1995-10-02          2                  5      1995-10-05
7      3  1995-10-03          3                  5      1995-10-05
8      3  1995-10-04          4                  5      1995-10-05
9      3  1995-10-05          5                  5      1995-10-05
10     4  1995-10-03          1                  2      1995-10-04
11     4  1995-10-04          2                  2      1995-10-04
```